# Error on emit a Sequelize result with Socket.io [Express, Socket.io, Sequelize]

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, sequelize.js

I have a simple put request on my Express API and after I do an update using the Sequelize ORM, I cannot emit with Socket.io.

I can only emit other objects, for example, I can emit this {"hello": "world"}, but I can not emit the result of the update.

Here it is the block of code:

```
module.exports = {
  async update(req, res) {
    const { body } = req;
    const { task_id } = req.params;

    const task = await ProjectTask.findByPk(task_id);

    task.update({
      name: body.title,
      description: body.description,
    });


    req.io.emit('update', task); // Here it is the socket.io that brakes the code
    console.log(task); // this works 


    return res.json(task); // also this
  },
}
```

Error: 
(node:8923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:99:24)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:126:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
    at _removeBlobs (/Users/guifeliper/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js:130:9)
(node:8923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8923) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

EDIT: Could it be because a item format? 
This is what we have on task variable:

```
{
  "id": 10971,
  "name": "Change the background image 5",
  "description": "save description 2",
  "dueEndDate": null,
  "status": 3,
  "deleted": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "closed": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-12-18T16:06:57.000Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2019-12-21T14:43:39.000Z",
  "sprint_id": 41
}
```

Not parsed:

```
ProjectTask {
  dataValues:
   { id: 10971,
     name: 'Change the background image 5',
     description: 'save description 2',
     dueEndDate: null,
     status: 3,
     deleted: <Buffer 00>,
     closed: <Buffer 00>,
     createdAt: 2019-12-18T16:06:57.000Z,
     modifiedAt: 2019-12-21T14:43:39.000Z,
     sprint_id: 41 },
  _previousDataValues:
   { id: 10971,
     name: 'Change the background image 5',
     description: 'save description 2',
     dueEndDate: null,
     status: 3,
     deleted: <Buffer 00>,
     closed: <Buffer 00>,
     createdAt: 2019-12-18T16:06:57.000Z,
     modifiedAt: 2019-12-21T14:43:39.000Z,
     sprint_id: 41 },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: true,
     underscored: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { id: '10971' },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'ProjectTasks', singular: 'ProjectTask' },
     omitNull: false,
     createdAt: 'createdAt',
     updatedAt: 'modifiedAt',
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [MysqlDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: {} },
     hooks: {} },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes:
      [ 'id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'dueEndDate',
        'status',
        'deleted',
        'closed',
        'createdAt',
        'modifiedAt',
        'sprint_id' ] },
  isNewRecord: false }
```

Comment: Show the content of `task`.

Comment: Added the not parsed version as well, thanks Marcos.

Comment: That's the issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used sequelize, but `task` definitely have some circular references in it.

So you can either use `raw: true` option in your `sequelize` query, or just send the properties you want using `.toJSON`, destructuring or similar.

You mention that you have a "parsed" version of the object, send that instead of the sequelize object.

Aside from using `raw`, the following should work:

```
req.io.emit('update', task.toJSON()); // will only have table attributes
```

```
req.io.emit('update', JSON.stringify(task)); // you'll get it as string in FE
```

Comment: I have tried the `raw: true`, but sadly didn't work. I mean the res.json return just the raw data (json).

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis check updated answer, use `.toJSON` or one of the other alternatives.

Comment: Awesome, just worked the .toJSON() and also the JSON.stringify(task). 
Do you know what is happening here? 
Is it just a circular reference? Because I am reusing task everytime?

Comment: No, it's not because of the sequelize properties that reference themselves. In any case you only want to send the table data. So that's why you use `.toJSON`